# USB device over current status detected

Tags: usb, motherboard, hardware-failure

I got a new pc last year and not playing games it works fine but after playing for example gta v it shuts off with the error message USB device over current status detected and i need to wait a while before turning it on again.

Any way to see which of my usb device is causing this issue without testing every subset of connected devices to see if it will happen (not even possible since it only happens after playing gta for a couple hours).

Any software to help debug this issue for super users?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Tester-Eversame-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Braided/dp/B07MGQZHGM/ref=sr_1_4_sspa?keywords=usb+power+meter&qid=1675437203&sr=8-4-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyWVNKR0ZNNkxDQUlUJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMzI3MDIwUkJBRE5FMjZWTDA0JmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA0ODk0NDgxRlVLRzdSUDlJUUlQJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==  You plug each device one at a time into this meter and see what device using the most power.  This is only 1 of dozens of similar devices.

Comment: Answer: it was a bad memory stick.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, just by testing them one at a time.

One of your usb devices or cables is probably either partially shorted (and goes after getting too hot for too long), or could be getting too hot in general. You might be able to wiggle them and trigger it.

Usually once something is shorted, it stays that way and keeps the pc from turning on (easy to find which one). You mention you "have to wait a while before turning it on again"?  You should be able to test them easily while it's keeping you from turning on the PC.